# How do I set an error page to an external location without a redirect?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use nginx to set up a SPA at an external location. I want

- all the /api requests to go to the api server
- all other requests to go to the static server (node:8081)
- otherwise, all requests should show the *content* of the root of the static server.

This is my *nginx.conf*

```
events { }
http {
     server {
            location / {
                     proxy_pass http://node:8081/;
                     proxy_intercept_errors on;
                     error_page 404 @fallback;
            }
            location /api/ {
                     proxy_pass http://play:9000/api/;
            }
            location @fallback {
                     proxy_pass http://node:8081;
            }
     }
}
```

However, with this configuration nginx serves a 301 result and redirects the browser to the root of the static server, but the SPA needs the URL in order to show the proper (SPA) view.

How do I configure the error_page to display the content of `http://node:8081` without redirecting there?

Comment: What is the content of `http:/node:8081`?

Comment: @bman70 It's the SPA, in full.

Comment: I don't have a clear picture of the setup but if it was my server I'd probably try something like this - assuming you know the file name to serve as `index` for `@fallback`: https://i.imgur.com/7aIVGiV.png

Comment: That would work, I think, but it would require having two copies of the homepage, which I'd like to avoid. I'd like to separate the SPA from the nginx concern, if possible.

Comment: Try adding `rewrite ^ / break;` to the `location @fallback` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith No luck.